# Why doesn't read 2 strings?

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int k;
    cout << "inserisci k: ";
    cin >> k;
    string stringa1;//nb
    string stringa2;//m

    cout<<"inserisci nb:";
    getline(cin, stringa1);

    cout<<"inserisci m:";
    getline(cin, stringa2);

    cout<<"nb: "<<stringa1<<endl;
    cout<<"m: "<<stringa2<<endl;

}
```

hi, i'd like to read string like 
"n b
m1 m2 ... mn" but i don't understand because my code doesn't work. lines

```
cout<<"inserisci nb:";
getline(cin, stringa1);
```

don't work but

```
cout<<"inserisci m:";
getline(cin, stringa2);
```

work perfectly. can you help me? thanks.

Comment: `getline()` causes problems when used with `cin`. Add `cin.ignore()`. Also use either `string` or `cstring`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following syntax of `getline`:

```cpp
std::getline(std::cin, str, 's');
```

It accepts a third argument as the character at which it will stop. Although optional, it matters here because `std::cin` leaves a newline character `\n`.

Use `cin.ignore()`, since if `getline()` is not provided with a character to stop (as the third argument), it will stop when it reaches a newline.

```cpp
    cout<<"inserisci nb:";
    getline(cin.ignore(), stringa1);

    cout<<"inserisci m:";
    getline(cin.ignore(), stringa2);
```

Answer (score 1):

After the `cin` to read `k`, it leaves a newline character.

But `getline` stops reading input after seeing that newline character. So you would need to remove that `\n`. One way is to call before the first `getline` call:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

(Need to include `<limits>` header).